# Click on progressbar to seek MediaPlayer

Tags: java, progress-bar, media-player

I have a music player that has a `ProgressBar` that has a max value of `mediaPlayer.getTotalDuration().toSeconds()`

Recently I have been trying to make a `MouseListener` to seek the `mediaPlayer` to the returned X value when the `ProgressBar` is clicked on a certain position.

The problem: I click on the `ProgressBar` and it appears to be receiving milliseconds so I multiply it by 1000 so it seeks to the corresponding second-count.

This works accurately for some music/mp3s but for shorter ones, or some longer ones, the `ProgressBar` only jumps to the nearest possible position, or jumps to some other position, completely inaccurate due to the `* 1000` calculation of the X value. (Below I've tried someone's suggestion for another answer to calculate the X value to seconds and I have also tried setting the `ProgressBar` value and setting that value to where the `mediaPlayer` is.)

"int point" is where I receive the X value.

Code:

```
progressBar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseClick) {
        try{
            progressBar.setMaximum((int)mediaPlayer.getTotalDuration().toSeconds());
            int point = (int)Math.round(((double)mouseClick.getX() / (double)progressBar.getWidth()) * progressBar.getMaximum()); // previously tried "* 1000".
            Duration pointDuration = new Duration(point);
            mediaPlayer.seek(pointDuration);
        } catch (Exception e7){
                //
        }
    }
});
```

(Unfortunately that calculation is even worse.)

What sort of calculation should I use to correctly seek to the clicked position?

Comment: A [`Slider`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html) might be a better solution for this than a ProgressBar.  If you wanted you could use CSS to style the slider to look like a ProgressBar or at least different from its default look.  For info on how to do this with a Slider, see the Oracle [Introduction to JavaFX Media](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/overview.htm) tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose your units wisely, and to make them appear in your code. What I usually do is to limit the progressbar to a [0.0,1.0] range, i.e. a percentage with `double` arithmetic.

When you receive a mouse click event you convert the event position in that [0,1] range.

Two things are needed:

1. the width (in pixels) of the progressbar
2. the x-coordinate of the mouseclick relative to progressbar component

And you have an accurate point (note `toMilliseconds`):

```
double dx = evt.getX();
double dwidth = progressBar.getWidth();
double progression = (dx / dwidth);
int milliseconds = (progression * mediaPlayer.getTotalDuration().toMilliseconds())
Duration duration = new Duration(milliseconds);
mediaPlayer.seek(duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well 1st mistake you make is setting progressBar maximum value when you click the progress bar. While media is playing and you did not pressed progressBar yet the max value of progres bar is wrong. This value should be set when the mediaPlayer duration is changed. You should add listener to totalDurationProperty change in same method that mediaPlayer got media assigned.

```
Media media = new Media(filePath);
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
mainMediaView.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);

mediaPlayer.totalDurationProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Duration>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observable, Duration oldValue,
                        Duration newValue) {
                    progressBar.setMax(newValue.toSeconds());
                }
            });
```

2nd problem is that Slider component and its progress bar have different sizes.

progressBar mouse listener:

```
progressBar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseClick) {
        try{
          double value;
          value = (mouseClick.getX()-9) * (progressBar.getMax() / (progressBar.getWidth()-19));
          progressBar.setValue(value); 
        } catch (Exception e7){

        }
    }
});
```

You might ask how did -9 and -19 showed up in there. Got those values by trial and error. As Slider component is larger than its progress bar getWidth() returns larger value. That includes gap on both sides of progress bar. -9 is for adjusting click position to gap between slider component and beginning of progress bar. -19 thats slider component width smaller by gaps on both sides of progress bar.